# How do I go back in TeXShop?

Tags: texshop

Suppose I am writing a line (call it "line a") in the editor, compiling it, and going to see it on the viewer.
Now, in the viewer, I am scrolling to another line (call it "line b") , and doing Cmd+click to go to line b in the editor.
Now I want to go back to line a in the editor. 
How do I do that?
In eclipse, and also in TexPad, there is a "go back" button. Is there a similar button on TeXShop?

Comment: There is no such function in TeXShop that I am aware of.

Comment: Do you use any workaround for the above scenario?

Comment: I don't use Texshop, so I have no idea how the program works, but I can imagine two scenarios: 1) pdf viewer are in the same window, than just click in the editor side to resume typing at line a, since the courser should be still there  2) pdf and editor are in different windows, then you can use native mac shortcuts. I think cycling through open application (in the order of last usage) is `cmd+tab` and windows of the same application is `cmd+[the caracter to mark inline code which does not get displayed in comments :(]`

Comment: (cont.) See http://osxdaily.com/2012/06/08/14-must-know-tips-tricks-for-mac-os-x/ for details about these shortcuts.

Comment: Thanks. However, the scenario I described is a bit different: I was editing some line "a", then went to edit another line "b", which is now sseen both on the editor and the viewer. So the cursor no is in "b", while I want to go back to "a" (this happens e.g. when fixing a definition while proving a subsequent lemma).

Comment: @YoniZohar: Try this: in the Preview window press the Back Arrow (small left facing arrow in the tool bar). Hopefully it will take you back to your previous location in the Preview pdf. Then use Cmd-Click at the point to take you back to point a.

Comment: continued: There is also a setup you can make for your keyboard that works under OS X and all apps that use Apple's Text Frameworks. It allows you to set (as single) hidden ``book mark'' and gives commands that allow you to swap that ``book mark'' and the indicator at the present location. Download  KeyBindings.zip from <https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/10932738/index.html>. It contains instructions. PS: it behaves like emacs' Swap Point & Mark command.

Comment: The small back button seems exactly like what I was looking for!

Comment: @HerbSchulz Can you write up an answer, please?

Answer (score 3):

In the Preview window press the small left facing black arrow. That takes you back to your previous location. Then Cmd-Click to take you back to that location in your Source window.

Comment: Clever! I wouldn’t have thought of that :-)