# Cycling between current position and last position in source, in TeXShop

Tags: texshop

When using TeXShop, I would like to to cycle between the last place I was in within my source, and my current place.

For instance, if I jump to a new place on my source, to copy a block of text, then I want to return to my previous place 5 pages earlier, it would be nice if I could cycle back and forth.

To see what I mean, you can try the same thing while looking at a PDF in Mac's Preview, and using Cmd+[ and Cmd+]. I would like to replicate this for TeXShop's source.

Comment: How do you jump to a new place? If:"Page down" then solution is "Page up", If:"Arrow down" then "Arrow up", ...

Comment: See also: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/321567/how-do-i-go-back-in-texshop

Comment: Please see the answer to [https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/606276/](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/606276/)